# Retain formatting

Tags: python, formatting

Im using a function to return a text file that is tab delimited and read in, the format of the text file is:

> 1_0     NP_250397       100.00  140    0       0       1       140     1     140     6e-54    198
>
> 1_0     NP_250378       60.00  140     0       0       1       140     1       140     6e-54    198
>
> 1_0     NP_257777       70.00  140     0       0       1       140     1       140     6e-54    198

My code used to return is:

```
def print_file(x):
    h = open('/home/me/data/db/test.blast', 'r')
    return h.readlines()
```

But when its printed it looks like:

> ['1_0\tNP_250397\t100.00\t140\t0\t0\t1\t140\t1\t140\t6e-54\t
> 198\n',
> '1_0\tNP_250397\t100.00\t140\t0\t0\t1\t140\t1\t140\t6e-54\t
> 198\n',
> '1_0\tNP_250397\t100.00\t140\t0\t0\t1\t140\t1\t140\t6e-54\t
> 198\n']

Is there a way of returning the file, while aslo retaining formatting?

Comment: What is the "x" supposed to do in the print_file function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want print_file to actually print the file as the function name suggests

```
def print_file(x):
    with open('/home/me/data/db/test.blast', 'r') as h:
        for line in h:
            print line
```

If you want to return the contents of the file as a single string

```
def print_file(x):
    with open('/home/me/data/db/test.blast', 'r') as h:
        return h.read()
```

If your Python is too old to use the with statement

```
def print_file(x):
    return open('/home/me/data/db/test.blast', 'r').read()
```

Aside: You may be interested to know that the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) can work with tab delimited files too

Comment: @Gary, if you are using python2.5 include this line at the top of the file `from __future__ import with_statement`

Comment: Thank you, your last messgae didnt appear until i submitted my last comment

Answer (score 0):

`return h.read()` would return the file's contents as a single string, and therefore "retain formatting" if that's printed, as you put it.  What other constraints do you have on the return value of the peculiarly-named `print_file` (peculiarly indeed because it doesn't *print* anything!)...?

Comment: h.readlines() is returned to another python script where it is printed

Comment: @Gary, if printing it is all that's needed then `h.read()` is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you print out a list, Python prints the list in a kind of raw format that represents how it's stored internally. If you want to eliminate the brackets and commas and quotes and want the tabs expanded, you must print out each string individually.

```
for line in print_file(x):
    print line
```

And could you please pick a more appropriate name for `print_file`, since it isn't really printing anything? It's adding a bit of cognitive dissonance that isn't helping your problem.